# Component local state is not getting State while using collapse

Tags: javascript, reactjs, html, redux, react-state

I am new to `react.js`. Here I have a button, on click of that button one dropdown gets opened.

```
export default class NewCollapse extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      quizEnable: false,
      viewEnable: false,
      uploadEnable: false
    }
  }
  EnableQuiz = () => {
    this.setState({
      quizEnable: true,
      viewEnable: false,
      uploadEnable: false
    });
  }
  EnableView = () => {
    this.setState({
      quizEnable: false,
      viewEnable: true,
      uploadEnable: false
    });
  }

  EnableUpload = () => {
    this.setState({
      quizEnable: false,
      viewEnable: false,
      uploadEnable: true
    });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div class="container">
        <div id="mainmenu" class="row">
          <div class="list-group panel visible-md visible-lg">
            <a href="#" class="list-group-item"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></i></a>
          </div>
          <div class="list-group panel">
            <button href="#menupos1" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#mainmenu">Quick Action<span class="menu-ico-collapse"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></i></span></button>
            <div class="collapse pos-absolute" id="menupos1">
              <a href="#submenu1" onClick={this.EnableQuiz} class="list-group-item sub-item" data-toggle={this.state.viewEnable === true ? "collapse" : "#"} data-parent="#submenu1">Quiz<span class=" menu-ico-collapse"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></i></span></a>
              <div class="collapse list-group-submenu" id="submenu1">
                <a href="#" class="list-group-item sub-sub-item" data-parent="#submenu1">
                  <img src={CreateNewQuizIcon} className="img-thumbnail menu-icons" />
                  <label className="list-component">Create New</label>
                </a>
                <a href="#" class="list-group-item sub-sub-item" data-parent="#submenu1">
                  <img src={ViewQuizIcon} className="img-thumbnail menu-icons" />
                  <label className="list-component">View</label>
                </a>
                <a href="#" class="list-group-item sub-sub-item" data-parent="#submenu1">
                  <img src={EditQuizIcon} className="img-thumbnail menu-icons" />
                  <label className="list-component">Update</label>
                </a>
              </div>
              <a href="#submenu2" onClick={this.EnableView} class="list-group-item sub-item" data-toggle={this.state.viewEnable === true ? "collapse" : "#"} data-parent="#submenu2">View<span class=" menu-ico-collapse"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></i></span></a>
              <div class="collapse list-group-submenu" id="submenu2">
                <a href="#" class="list-group-item sub-sub-item" data-parent="#submenu2">
                  <img src={JobDescriptionIcon} className="img-thumbnail menu-icons" />
                  <label className="list-component">Job Description</label>
                </a>
                <a href="#" class="list-group-item sub-sub-item" data-parent="#submenu2">
                  <img src={ResumeIcon} className="img-thumbnail menu-icons" />
                  <label className="list-component">Resume</label>
                </a>

              </div>
              <a href="#submenu3" onClick={this.EnableUpload} class="list-group-item sub-item" data-toggle={this.state.uploadEnable === true ? "collapse" : "#"} data-parent="#submenu3">Upload<span class=" menu-ico-collapse"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></i></span></a>
              <div class="collapse list-group-submenu" id="submenu3" >
                <a href="#" class="list-group-item sub-sub-item" data-parent="#submenu3">
                  <img src={UploadFolderIcon} className="img-thumbnail menu-icons" />
                  <label className="list-component">Folder</label>
                </a>
                <a href="#" class="list-group-item sub-sub-item" data-parent="#submenu3">
                  <img src={UploadResumeIcon} className="img-thumbnail menu-icons" />
                  <label className="list-component">Resume</label>
                </a>
              </div>
              <a href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#menupos1" class="list-group-item sub-item">
                <img src={DownloadTrackerIcon} className="img-thumbnail menu-icons" />
                <label className="list-component">Download Tracker</label>
              </a>
              <a href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#menupos1" class="list-group-item sub-item">
                <img src={SelectionCriteriaIcon} className="img-thumbnail menu-icons" />
                <label className="list-component">Selection Criteria</label>
              </a>
              <a href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#menupos1" class="list-group-item sub-item">
                <img src={RemoveIcon} className="img-thumbnail menu-icons" />
                <label className="list-component">Remove</label>
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

So, here what I want to do is that there are three buttons, if any of them is collapsed the others should not be. So, I have maintained three states for each of the collapse. Now, state gets changed but when I first click, that time the state is not getting changed.

So, what is it that I am doing wrong?

Can any one help me with this?

Comment: Is it working when you click it the second time?

Comment: yes it is working for second time

Comment: what library are u using? Bootstrap? I'll try to build this and see what i can do,.

Comment: you don't need 90% of that - one prop in the state (opened id) and conditional rendering for show/hide submenus - search for any react accordion tutorial/example

Comment: yes I am using bootstrap 4

Comment: @xadm could you please tell me hOW CAN i DO THAT ?

Comment: I wrote HOW in general - details? just use search, google and learn from other people's code/solutions

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using bootstrap, there is really no easy way for us to change the collapse/show functionality being provided to us. What we can do is work our way around it with some conditional-rendering.

```
export default class NewCollapse extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      quizEnable: false,
      viewEnable: false,
      uploadEnable: false
    };
  }
  enableQuiz = () => {
    this.setState({
      quizEnable: true,
      viewEnable: false,
      uploadEnable: false
    });
  };
  enableView = () => {
    this.setState({
      quizEnable: false,
      viewEnable: true,
      uploadEnable: false
    });
  };

  enableUpload = () => {
    this.setState({
      quizEnable: false,
      viewEnable: false,
      uploadEnable: true
    });
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <div id="mainmenu" className="row">
          <div className="list-group panel visible-md visible-lg">
            <a href="/" className="list-group-item">
              <i className="glyphicon glyphicon-home" />
            </a>
          </div>
          <div className="list-group panel">
            <button
              href="#menupos1"
              data-toggle="collapse"
              data-parent="#mainmenu"
            >
              Quick Action
              <span className="menu-ico-collapse">
                <i className="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down" />
              </span>
            </button>
            <div className="collapse pos-absolute" id="menupos1">
              <span
                href="#submenu1"
                onClick={this.enableQuiz}
                className={
                  this.state.quizEnable
                    ? "list-group-item sub-item"
                    : "list-group-item sub-item collapsed"
                }
                data-toggle="collapse"
                data-parent="#submenu1"
                aria-expanded={this.state.quizEnable}
              >
                Quiz
                <span class=" menu-ico-collapse">
                  <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down" />
                </span>
              </span>
              <div
                className={
                  this.state.quizEnable
                    ? "list-group-submenu collapse show"
                    : "collapse list-group-submenu"
                }
                id="submenu1"
              >
                <a
                  href="#"
                  class="list-group-item sub-sub-item"
                  data-parent="#submenu1"
                >
                  <img
                    src={CreateNewQuizIcon}
                    className="img-thumbnail menu-icons"
                  />
                  <label className="list-component">Create New</label>
                </a>
                <a
                  href="#"
                  class="list-group-item sub-sub-item"
                  data-parent="#submenu1"
                >
                  <img
                    src={ViewQuizIcon}
                    className="img-thumbnail menu-icons"
                  />
                  <label className="list-component">View</label>
                </a>
                <a
                  href="#"
                  class="list-group-item sub-sub-item"
                  data-parent="#submenu1"
                >
                  <img
                    src={EditQuizIcon}
                    className="img-thumbnail menu-icons"
                  />
                  <label className="list-component">Update</label>
                </a>
              </div>
              <span
                href="#submenu2"
                onClick={this.enableView}
                className={
                  this.state.viewEnable
                    ? "list-group-item sub-item"
                    : "list-group-item sub-item collapsed"
                }
                data-toggle="collapse"
                data-parent="#submenu2"
                aria-expanded={this.state.viewEnable}
              >
                View
                <span className=" menu-ico-collapse">
                  <i className="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down" />
                </span>
              </span>
              <div
                className={
                  this.state.viewEnable
                    ? "list-group-submenu collapse show"
                    : "collapse list-group-submenu"
                }
                id="submenu2"
              >
                <a
                  href="#"
                  className="list-group-item sub-sub-item"
                  data-parent="#submenu2"
                >
                  <img
                    src={{JobDescriptionIcon}}
                    className="img-thumbnail menu-icons"
                  />
                  <label className="list-component">Job Description</label>
                </a>
                <a
                  href="#"
                  className="list-group-item sub-sub-item"
                  data-parent="#submenu2"
                >
                  <img
                    src={ResumeIcon} 
                    className="img-thumbnail menu-icons"
                  />
                  <label className="list-component">Resume</label>
                </a>
              </div>
              <span
                href="#submenu3"
                onClick={this.enableUpload}
                className={
                  this.state.uploadEnable
                    ? "list-group-item sub-item"
                    : "list-group-item sub-item collapsed"
                }
                data-toggle="collapse"
                data-parent="#submenu3"
                aria-expanded={this.state.uploadEnable}
              >
                Upload
                <span className=" menu-ico-collapse">
                  <i className="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down" />
                </span>
              </span>
              <div
                className={
                  this.state.uploadEnable
                    ? "list-group-submenu collapse show"
                    : "collapse list-group-submenu"
                }
                id="submenu3"
              >
                <a
                  href="#"
                  className="list-group-item sub-sub-item"
                  data-parent="#submenu3"
                >
                  <img
                    src={UploadFolderIcon}
                    className="img-thumbnail menu-icons"
                  />
                  <label className="list-component">Folder</label>
                </a>
                <a
                  href="#"
                  className="list-group-item sub-sub-item"
                  data-parent="#submenu3"
                >
                  <img
                    src={UploadResumeIcon}
                    className="img-thumbnail menu-icons"
                  />
                  <label className="list-component">Resume</label>
                </a>
              </div>
              <a
                href="#"
                data-toggle="collapse"
                data-target="#menupos1"
                className="list-group-item sub-item"
              >
                <img src={DownloadTrackerIcon} className="img-thumbnail menu-icons" />
                <label className="list-component">Download Tracker</label>
              </a>
              <a
                href="#"
                data-toggle="collapse"
                data-target="#menupos1"
                className="list-group-item sub-item"
              >
                <img src={SelectionCriteriaIcon} className="img-thumbnail menu-icons" />
                <label className="list-component">Selection Criteria</label>
              </a>
              <a
                href="#"
                data-toggle="collapse"
                data-target="#menupos1"
                className="list-group-item sub-item"
              >
                <img src={RemoveIcon} className="img-thumbnail menu-icons" />
                <label className="list-component">Remove</label>
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Okay I will check with this and let u know

Comment: actually, what is happening is that if one is open and if I try to open the secon that time the first one should have closed but that is not happening.

Comment: In the sandbox also this thing is happening.

Comment: oh that's what you meant. okay let me take another stab at this :)

Comment: @ganesh please try the sandbox now. I think it provides the functionality you are looking for.

Comment: @ganesh did that sandbox work for you? I mean I could update your code, but I think you really just need to extract the html I wrote to get your app to work. I also don't have access to your images.

Comment: yes  that is working. It would be really helpful if you just review the html part, as I am new so .. I will create some small components for this

Comment: Actually, what is happening is that , this main button is in a table . So it is present in the td. Now, Here when I click on the main button which actually opens the collpase it also takes the whole td's height. so that td becomes big.

Comment: On click of a single button also other rows are also getting oopen

Comment: I think there is an issue with the state, as every element is using the same state so that's why it is opening the others.

Comment: Nope I tried a lot but not able to solve this thning .

Comment: @ganeshkaspate. Hmm I'm not sure what else I can do to help you friend. Is my code sandbox not performing the functionality you need?